# Scrolling in example Cover bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner in html / css and I'm implementing a site over the bootstrap cover example (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/).
I am using this same layout for the Home, Features and Contatc pages. But in the Features page I have a much larger content that needs a scroll. But this css does not allow this, causes the elements to be positioned in the center and the page maintaining the size of the browser screen.
I would like to change so that the page grows according to the amount of content that I add (without fixed size) maintaining the same style of the layout and also another problem that I had in my tests is the navbar was fixed and over the content during the Scrolling.

CSS:

```
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {

height: 1000px;
/*
padding-bottom: 70px;
padding-top: 70px;*/
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
            <p class="lead">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some `fixed` `position` s on media querys which cause this.

Comment the following properties inside of `@media (min-width: 768px)`:

```
.masthead {
    /* position: fixed; */
    /* top: 0; */
}
.mastfoot {
    /* position: fixed; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
}
```

**[---> Check working Fiddle here <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/18/)**

- Note I added `background: gray` to `body` just to see the `nav` links.

[image]

Scrolls down to:

[image]